# I want to get last inserted value from table 'Project' in Stored Procedure..I am using IDENT_CURRENT('Project') but its not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
Procedure [dbo].[spViewdetail]
    @ProjectID int
as 
    declare @Proj_Id int
Begin
    Select @Proj_Id=ProjectID from Project where ProjectID=@ProjectID
        if(@Proj_Id=0)
        BEGIN
            SET @Proj_Id= IDENT_CURRENT('Project')
            SELECT o.OpportunityName, pt.ProjectType, u.Name, 
            u.MobileNumber, u.EmailAddress, p.ProjectOwner,p.ProjectName, p.ProjectID, 
            p.ProjectOwnerMobileNumber, p.RAndDKitchen,  p.WTIProduct, 
            p.Regulatory, p.ProcessingMethod, p.PreparationMethod, 
            p.PackingType, p.FoodItemSource, p.aw, p.fat, p.SodiumContent, 
            p.Protien,  p.Customer, p.DirectorOfSale, p.TechnicalManager, 
            p.LabDirector,  p.RAndDKitchenManger, p.FoodItem, 
            p.OpportunityOwner,  p.OpportunityOwnerMobileNumber from dbo.Project as p
            inner join dbo.Opportunity as o on p.OpportunityId=o.OpportunityId
            inner join dbo.ProjectType as pt on p.ProjectTypeId=pt.ProjectTypeId
            inner join dbo.Users as u on p.UserId=u.UserId
            where p.ProjectID=@Proj_Id
        END
END
```

Comment: Hi, it's not possible to get IDENT_CURRENT in out of diff transaction. Please use same SP for insert a record  and get a IDENT_CURRENT in same SP.

Comment: Is `Project_Id` an `INT IDENTITY` column? THen just use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` **after** the insert to get the newly inserted ID back

Comment: @vikramjain Is there any other solution for get last inserted value in my sp?

Comment: @marc_s, Yes Project_Id is Int IDENTITY column... But i wan something different like want Project_id using these SP.. Is it Possible or not??

Comment: But you're already passing in the `Project_ID` here .... so you want back the same value that you passed in?!?!?! Doesn't really make sense.....

Comment: @marc_s.. this sp is not completed.. and i want to store info in some page and immediately showing the info of recently registered user in different page... So show their info in another page i want last inserted Project_Id..

Answer (score 0):

As Project_Id an INT IDENTITY column, and for every new entry ProjectID will be incremented, You can select max(project_id) to get last inserted row.

```
declare @Proj_Id int;
Select @Proj_Id = max(ProjectID) from Project
```

Comment: Its not pic the last inserted value... when i execute the sp, it is returning 0 and not showing the column values..

Comment: that might be because of your join condition. You can execute 
below mentioned query in Managment studio to check if it return the last inserted project. "Select max(ProjectID) from Project"